# passing parameters to JSON object dynamiclly

Tags: java, servlets

**What I have :**
Servlet at server end. 
HTML at client sending requests via Ajax to servlet

1. The data that servlet provide is in database.
2. Servlet needs to retrieve data based on parameter values provided at run time.

3.Html display charts based on data retrieved from the servlet.

Parameter names and values are sent from client end like this :

```
var dataString ={"Id": 1, "Value" : 30 };
```

Now, at servlet end, I had parameter names embedded statically and values retrieved from database for those parameters. I did something like this for that matter:

```
while(rs.next())
{
int Id1 = rs.getInt(1);
System.out.println("Id " + Id1);
String Patient  = rs.getString(2);
System.out.println("Name " + Patient );
String Dept  = rs.getString(3);
System.out.println("Dept " + Dept );
int Val  = rs.getInt(4);
System.out.println("Value " + Val);
obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("Id", Id1);
obj.put("PatientName", Patient);
obj.put("Department", Dept);
obj.put("Value", Val);
Details.add(obj);
}
```

**What I want:** I need all these parameter names to be dynamic based on what was passed from client end:

**What I tried and where I am stuck:**

```
Enumeration params =request.getParameterNames();
while(params.hasMoreElements())
{

   obj.put(params.nextElement(), how to get this value from database here? );
}
```

Please guide me through this. That will be a great help. Thank you.
Also, where I do resultset.getString or resultSet.getInt , how do I figure it dynamically if it has to be a string or an int?

Comment: Your question has three tags and they all refer to the JavaScript language. However, all your code samples are clearly not JavaScript. Do you know what programming language you're using?

Comment: I am using Servlet at backend. I had asked a couple of question in ajax before so probably out of habit I ended up tagging wrong here. I will just edit that. thanks

Comment: Fair enough. You'd be surprised to see how misguided some devs can be :)